# After RN/Xcode upgrade `FirebaseCoreInternal.modulemap' not found`

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

**How can I restore a successful build process?**

After manually [upgrading](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.70.2&to=0.72.0) from RN version 0.70.2 to RN version 0.72.0 using a new project with code copied from my existing project, the new and existing project will no longer build using Xcode. I'm tying to build according to `Any iOS Device (arm64)`, which normally works. Here is the error:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project-name>-aobgsqdmebtxwebkbxofzpscossc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/<project-name>.build/Debug-iphoneos/<project-name>.build/DerivedSources/<project-name>_vers.c module map file '~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<project-name>-aobgsqdmebtxwebkbxofzpscossc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCoreInternal/FirebaseCoreInternal.modulemap' not found
```

When I look up modulemap files it seems to be related to manually linking files which is no longer applicable so I'm left confused.

I have added `GoogleService-Info.plist` and checked to ensure the [configuration code](https://rnfirebase.io/#configure-firebase-with-ios-credentials) for FireBase was retained to the best of my ability.

A similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69319871/fastlane-deploy-ios-fatal-error-yogakit-modulemap-not-found) has no accepted solution, but I should mention I have tried the obvious suggestions: close and reopen Xcode, clean before building, changing the minimum `iOS Deployment Target`, and removing `node_modules` and `Pods/` folder before reinstalling using `yarn` and `pod install`.

Here is `npx react-native info` output:

```
System:
  OS: macOS 13.4
  CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8100B CPU @ 3.60GHz
  Memory: 183.78 MB / 8.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: 3.2.57
    path: /bin/bash
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 20.3.1
    path: /usr/local/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 1.21.1
    path: ~/npm-global/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 9.6.7
    path: /usr/local/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2023.06.12.00
    path: /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.12.1
    path: ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 22.4
      - iOS 16.4
      - macOS 13.3
      - tvOS 16.4
      - watchOS 9.4
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: Not Found
  Xcode:
    version: 14.3.1/14E300c
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java: Not Found
  Ruby:
    version: 2.7.5
    path: ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react: Not Found
  react-native: Not Found
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: false
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
```

Here is a snippet of changes to `package.json`:

```
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": [-"^16.4.0",-]{+"^18.1.0",+}
"@react-native-firebase/app": [-"^16.4.0",-]{+"^18.1.0",+}
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": [-"^16.4.0",-]{+"^18.1.0",+}
```

Comment: I receive the same issue. Have you solved it so far?

Comment: No, but I notice Xcode builds a "hello world" app just fine without RN and I haven't heard anything from the RN team on the related issue of new RN project builds on Xcode (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/38160)